# Export from pdf to excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am new in VBA and I'm getting a '[compile error: syntax[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l61sj.png)' when running this macro in VBA in
lines :

```
Call Shell( _
pathname:=shellPathName,
windowstyle:=vbNormalFocus)
```

The script that I am using is:

```
Sub pdf_ToExcell()

Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim adobeReaderPath As String
Dim pathAndFileName As String
Dim shellPathName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set myWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Adobe Acrobat Reader")

adobeReaderPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
pathAndFileName = "C:\Users\......pdf"

Call Shell( _
pathname:=shellPathName,
windowstyle:=vbNormalFocus)
    
Applications.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")

SendKeys "%vpc"
SendKeys "^a"
SendKeys "^c"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:30")

With myWorksheet
    .Range("B4").Select
    .PasteSpecial Format:="Text"
End With

Call Shell("TaskKill /F /IM AcroRd32.exe", vbHide)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Thank you for any advise.

Comment: Well for one you're missing the line continuation character `_`.

Comment: Thank you BigBen. However I have included it (see picture attached).

Comment: No, you're missing another one. You have three lines and are missing the line continuation after the second line.